# Need help for getting gap between two number in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, awk

I have i/p file below:

```
name 1
info 21
city 28
pin  31
state 34
   -   39
```

and looking o/P will be like:( ",l-" is constant for all row)

```
    20,l-name
    7,l-info
    3,l-city
    3,l-pin
    5,l-state
```

with below shell code:

```
awk 'NR>1{ printf "%d,l-%s\n", $2 - val, label } {label=$1; val=$2}' input
```

i am getting op like

```
1,
21,l-name 
24,l-info
28,l-city
```

but i need out as difference between two value like:

```
20,l-name
3,l-info
4,l-city
```

Here i want minus first number from second number as gap between it. Please help me...

Comment: What you posted is not shell code, it is awk code. Awk is a completely different tool/language from shell, though you can call awk scripts from shell just like you can call compiled C programs from shell.

Comment: btw **it is not possible** for the script you posted to produce the output you say it does from the input you posted. It's also very unclear why you expect to get the output you say you need given that input. In fact you state 2 very different "expected output"s from the same input so idk what you really want - should you get output of `7,l-info` or `3,l-info`? So please take another look at your example and make sure everything is consistent and *exactly** correct wrt your requirements and results so we're not trying to help you debug a problem other than whatever your actual problem is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk -v OFS=, 'NR>1{print ($2 - n), "l-" v} {v = $1; n = $2}' file

20,l-name
7,l-info
3,l-city
3,l-pin
5,l-state
```

- This awk`command stores every row's 2 columns in 2 variables`v`and`n`
- When row num is greater than one then we calculate difference and print it.

Comment: Oh downvote for a working answer without any comment, strange!!

Comment: Happens to me on a regular basis... I just chock it up to the phase of the moon if the downvoter doesn't have the integrity to comment. Looks like the moon is right (waxing crescent -- I'll have to remember that)

Comment: Thanks so much @DavidC.Rankin

Answer (score 0):

Weird - running that on my Mac gets the correct result :-

```
$ cat inp
name 1
info 21
city 28
pin  31
state 34
-   39 
$ awk 'NR>1{ printf "%d,l-%s\n", $2 - val, label } {label=$1; val=$2}' inp
20,l-name
7,l-info
3,l-city
3,l-pin
5,l-state
```

At a guess, you'll need to check the version of awk, because it doesn't seem to be obeying the `NR>1` pattern and isn't performing the `$2 - value` subtraction. 
Might be able to fix that by creating another variable, performing the subtraction, then performing the `printf`

```
$ awk 'val>0 {range=$2-val; printf "%d,l-%s\n", range, label } {label=$1; val=$2}' inp
```